# DbGeometry Contains() works only for Polygon WKT

Tags: c#, wkt

I tried the following code that behaves differently from what I expected.
The DbGeometry.FromText is supposed to create an object from WKT. However, the contains function only seems to work on Polygon WKT and not for circles or linestrings (I've drawn a diamond in the example). In these examples, all the geometries "contain" 0,0 but only polygon actually results the value I expected. Any idea of what's going on? Am I missing something in code or am I missing some theory about how DbGeometry works?

```
  DbGeometry point = DbGeometry.FromText("POINT (0 0)");

  DbGeometry circle = DbGeometry.FromText("CIRCULARSTRING(0 -1, 1 0, 0 1, -1 0, 0 -1)");
  Console.WriteLine(circle.Contains(point)); // returns false

  var diamond = DbGeometry.FromText("LINESTRING(0 -1, 1 0, 0 1, -1 0, 0 -1)");
  Console.WriteLine(diamond.Contains(point)); //returns false

  var polygon = DbGeometry.FromText("POLYGON((-1 -1, -1 1, 1 1, 1 -1, -1 -1))");
  Console.WriteLine(polygon.Contains(point)); //returns true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example `circle` doesn't contain `point` since it is a string and not a polygon. (However, something like `POINT(0 -1)` *is* on the example circlestring). Just because the circularstring is closed, doesn't make it a polygon.

I think what you want is `CURVEPOLYGON(CIRCULARSTRING(0 -1, 1 0, 0 1, -1 0, 0 -1))`, which *does* contain `POINT(0 0)`.

Lastly, not all implementations support curves, so you may need to use `STCurveToLine` to get a polygonal approximation of a geometry instance that contains curved segments.

Comment: Thanks. Although I'm currently using a Point with STBuffer to create a circle (as a DbGeometry\DbGeography object) that I then intersect with my point.